# Как закрыть всплывающее окно через Selenium webDriver (именно от сайта) Python?

Tags: python, selenium

При входе на сайт появляется всплывающее окно(не в вкладка и не сообщение от браузера)
Мне нужно или нажать на кнопку "Я понял" либо закрыть нажав на крестик.
Пробовал через swith_to(),но все что я нашел это как убрать окно именно от браузера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пример

Было бы отлично если бы вы объяснили как с ними работать или дали ссылку на какую либо статью/документацию.

Comment: Посмотрите, должно помочь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568508/selenium-switch-to-popup-window

Comment: Это он для пользователя выглядит как всплывающий диалог визуально, а по факту - самый обычный хтмл элемент, как и все остальные. Находите крестик обычными методами и кликайте.